# Im trying to add a tuple to a list on Ocaml

Tags: tuples, ocaml

Im trying to add a tuple of type (int*int) on a for cycle to a list but i get an error saying : this expression should have type unit.

this is what i have right now:

```
let addtuple k lst =
  for i=0 to k - 1 do 
    let (n,j) =Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun a b->(a,b))
 in
      (n,j)::lst
    done;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `for` you need to use `ref`:

```
let addtuple k lst = 
  let r = ref lst in
    for i = 1 to k do
      r := (Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun x y -> (x, y))) :: !r
    done;
    !r;;
```

A more functional approach using a recursive function:

```
let rec addtuple k lst =
  match k with
  | 0 -> lst
  | _ -> addtuple (k - 1) ((Scanf.scanf " %d %d" (fun x y -> (x, y))) :: lst);;
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the OCaml `for` is to *do* something, rather than compute a value. So the body of the loop should be an OCaml expression that has a useful side effect (like printing a value). For this reason, the body of a `for` loop should have the type `unit`, the type used for expressions that don't have an interesting value. But your loop has a body that is a list. The compiler is telling you (correctly) that this indicates that something is wrong.

Your code is written assuming that the expression `(n, j) :: lst` will change the value of `lst`. But this is not the case. In a functional language like OCaml, you can't change the values of variables.

If your function is supposed to return a list, it can't be based on a `for` loop, which always returns `()` (the unique value of type unit). Most likely it should be based on a fold (which accumulates a value while working through a series of inputs) or on your own recursive function.